# move_uploaded_file(...): failed to open stream: Permission denied in... Using Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: php, macos

So basically I have your classic 'move_uploaded_file' statement:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], 'files/' . $_FILES['image']['name']);
```

But I am getting this on my OS X Mountain Lion:

```
move_uploaded_file(...): failed to open stream: Permission denied in...
```

How can I change the permissions so I can move it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in MAC OS X's terminal ,use this commande :

```
  CHMOD 775 yourFilesPath
```

775:Standard file sharing mode for a group.

Comment: should be 766 to can write?

Comment: user has 7 and can write,but to avoid problems,i changed it to 775.

Comment: 775 better i thought :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note down since you are using xamp server which have the Application folder in Root

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/emp/files/admin_assets/addsdassets
```

so for uploading the image file you have to provide the target directory which should be present in the Root 
try with the same directory in which application is running

And then locate the xamp server location by clicking on **show original** on the mac after right click and then change the permission

for the images folder and the php file, by going to the file > Right click > Get info > and then change all the permissions to read&write as the following picture.

[image]