# File upload in php not working on remote server

Tags: php, html, file-upload

Here is the code which I am using

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

PHP code :

```
<?php
 $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmp_name  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$location = "/var/www/tmp/";
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
   echo 'File uploaded successfully';
 }  else {
  echo 'You should select a file to upload !!';
   }
     ?>
```

I checked the permissions of the folder as well as  checked the php.ini file but still always I am getting 'You should select a file to upload '

Can anybody please help me out on this issue ?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you checked about max file size in php.ini?

Comment: Thanks for reply! Yes I do have changed max file size from 2M to 128M.

Comment: your `$location` represents "to location" or "from location"?

Answer (score 1):

Give the full path of your file here

```html
$location = "var/www/tmp/";
```

I think it will work. If its ok then store your servername in a variable and pass there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried your suggestion but still I am getting false condition.

Comment: Yes sir, I tried with removing '/' still same outcome with false condition. Actually I tried in mac(OSX) also but there I am getting same result.

Comment: I am doing it in windows OS. Its coming fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370770/move-uploaded-file-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-in-using-ma .Try this, it may help you

Comment: So what system software version do you have (like apache,php) ?

Comment: php - 5.3.5, apache- 2.2

Comment: Actually I am doing this it in linux.

Answer (score 0):

Your Location should be like this:

```
// document root will give you the server root then you can add any directory after that (in your case its tmp I guess)
$location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/your_preferred_dir/'
```

> note: when you mention your preferred location you will have to make
>   sure that this location should exists otherwise it will cause error.

And not hardcoded as yours because it can change from server to server.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hello sagar, I tried with above command : $location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/var/www/html/tmp/' but with it gives no output niether true nor false.

Comment: Can you put what errors are you getting in your error log here..?